# Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, wav

```
import os
import speech_recognition as sr

command = "ffmpeg -i videototext.mp4 videototext.mp3"
os.system(command)

commandwav = "ffmpeg -i videototext.mp3 videototext.wav"
os.system(commandwav)

AUDIO_FILE = "videototext.wav"

r = sr.Recognizer()
videototext = sr.AudioFile(AUDIO_FILE)

with videototext as source:
   audio = r.record(source, duration=100)

print(type(audio))
print(r.recognize_google(audio))
```

---

above is my code,then the error is: Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format.

Comment: The answer to your question is exactly in the error message. Does your `ffmpeg` support mp3?

Comment: yes,videototext.mkv, videototext.mp3, videototext.wav are indeed generated in my folder, but the .txt file that the program will eventually generate because of this bug has never been generated:((

Comment: I am afraid I did not quite get your answer. Can you elaborate on your problem in the question and paste error in full, as produced by your program? Please don't do screenshots and mind formatting.

Comment: My main purpose is to convert a screen-recorded word file (from 0 to complete text) into a text file, and the screen-recorded file is an .mp4 file (without sound). Currently my program can convert the .mp4 into mp3, mkv, wav files. But because of this error: "Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format." I cannot generate the final text file. How should I solve this problem :((

Comment: When we ask to paste the error, it means you should paste the complete stack trace with the error, not just the message. For now it seems your `ffmpeg` does not support mp3.

Comment: 1) Copy and paste all of the text from the ffmpeg command. 2) Check if your command works if you run it manually, unscripted in a command-line interface. 3) Provide a link to a short sample input file that has the error.

Comment: ok thx a lot! My way to solve my problem is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

This was also driving me crazy;
Path was clearly the problem. There are several explanations like the one below that tell you to modify to
C:\ffmpeg\bin
(example: https://windowsloop.com/install-ffmpeg-windows-10/)
and others that explain same did not work.

My solution was to modify the path to anaconda3 path:
C:\Users\YOURPATH\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\bin

Then I needed to restart the computer for registry changes to take effect!

Don't forget that last step...

Unusual that ffmpeg can't create, use paths without user modification of paths (dirty).

Comment: what error did you get?